# How to add new fonts to kivy?

Tags: python, fonts, kivy

My code in python file is:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase


class ClockApp(App):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    LabelBase.register(name='Roboto',
                      fn_regular='Roboto-Thin.ttf',
                      fn_bold='Roboto-Medium.ttf')
    ClockApp().run()
```

and in kivy file:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Label:
        text: '00:00:00'
        font_name: 'Roboto'
        font_size: 60
```

But running the program raises the followig error:

```
File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kivy/core/text/__init__.py", line 315, in register
     raise IOError('File {0} not found'.format(font_type))
 OSError: File Roboto-Thin.ttf not found
```

I Download all Roboto font family members in .ttf format and save them in `~/.fonts` folder. But still error raises.

Comment: Prepend complete path, like `pre-path-to-font/Roboto-Thin.ttf`

Answer (score 1):

Copying the fonts to the `~./fonts` folder will not allow them to be recognized by kivy. You need to manually add them to kivy using their full path. I would suggest to keep your fonts with your project files as it will be easier to maintain the structure of your code.

For example:

```
LabelBase.register(name='Roboto',
                      fn_regular='/home/guhan/Documents/project/Roboto-Thin.ttf')
```

Here I have used my own path full path to the font.

Comment: As you say I store required font files in my projects folder and without adding any pre-path to ```.ttf``` files, program works properly. Thanks